# Variable not recognized in generate method

Tags: java, oop, variables, constructor

I created a `SandBox sb` in the no argument constructor `AsteroidGame()`, however the variable `sb` cannot be found in my generate method when I try to add objects to the `SandBox`. Any insight on where I'm going wrong?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new AsteroidGame();
    }

    public AsteroidGame()
    {      
        //Create SandBox
        SandBox sb = new SandBox();
        sb.init(this);
    }

    public void generate() 
    {
        //Instantiate Rocket and add it to Sandbox
        Dimension dime = sb.getPanelBounds();
        Rocket rock = new Rocket(dime.width/2, dime.height/2);
        sb.addBlob(rock);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do like this `Declare SandBox as instance/class variable`:

```
    SandBox sb; // Declare SandBox as instance/class variable
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            new AsteroidGame();
        }

        public AsteroidGame()
        {      
            //Create SandBox
            sb = new SandBox();
            sb.init(this);
        }

        public void generate() 
        {
            //Instantiate Rocket and add it to Sandbox
            Dimension dime = sb.getPanelBounds();
            Rocket rock = new Rocket(dime.width/2, dime.height/2);
            sb.addBlob(rock); 
    }
```

Or `Create a new local variable in`generate()`method:`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new AsteroidGame();
    }

    public AsteroidGame()
    {      
        //Create SandBox
        SandBox sb = new SandBox();
        sb.init(this);
    }

    public void generate() 
    {
        // Create a new local variable here
        SandBox sb = new SandBox();
        Dimension dime = sb.getPanelBounds();
        Rocket rock = new Rocket(dime.width/2, dime.height/2);
        sb.addBlob(rock); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Sanbox` variable is local variable mean it not visible out side you constructor function. If you want to use it in `generate` function you must convert it to `field` of your class

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is to initialize object of the same class not of any class.

> Constructor in java is a special type of method that is used to initialize the object.

Create `sb` in `generate` method itself.

And if `sb` is field member, use `sb = new SandBox();`instead of `SandBox sb = new SandBox();`